# How to use webpack 5 with nuxt3 project

Tags: webpack, nuxt.js, webpack-5, nuxtjs3

please can anyone help with the instruction of how to create nuxt3 project with webpack5 module bundler.
at nuxt3 official docs they mentioned that they support webpack5, without mentioning how to use it.
the default nuxt3 module bundler is Vite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for [Danielroe](https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/2740#discussioncomment-1979072) who answered my [Github discussion](https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/2740#discussioncomment-1979072)

You can enable Webpack by setting Vite to `false` on nuxt.config.ts:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  vite: false
})
```

Answer (score 6):

`vite: false` is deprecated, you can activate webpack as the bundler with this config:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  builder: 'webpack'
})
```

Comment: you will also have to install `"@nuxt/webpack-builder": "^3.0.0",`

Comment: is this again changed? I can't add builder field in the config.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using nuxt v3.5.0, maybe you can try the following way :

1. Change builder configuration in `nuxt.config.ts`

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  builder: 'webpack',
});
```

2. Add new package webpack builder

```bash
npm i @nuxt/webpack-builder
```

Now you can try `npm run dev` again, I hope this helps :D